# How to run file in subfolder

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import os

root_dir = "D:\extention"
for folder, subfolders, files in os.walk(root_dir):
    if folder != root_dir:
        for f in files:
            if f.endswith(".py"):
                print("File Name: ", f)
                print(f"Path: ", os.path.join(folder, f))
                dir_path=(f"Path: ", os.path.join(folder, f))
```

with this code i can find py file in subfolder but cant run the file

I try to use `os.system` but get error.

I have very little knowledge of python can anyone help me.

Comment: Missing `os.system` in your example. And what is the error message?

Comment: PS D:\extention> & "C:/Users/My Pc/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe" d:/extention/open.py
File Name:  webp.py
Path:  D:\extention\1\webp.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\extention\open.py", line 12, in <module>
    os.system(dir_path)
TypeError: system() argument 'command' must be str, not tuple

Comment: Do not post such error messages in the comments, it is horrible to read, please edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `dir_path` is a tuple not a string. Leave out the round brackets.

```
import os

root_dir = "D:\extention"
for folder, subfolders, files in os.walk(root_dir):
    if folder != root_dir:
        for f in files:
            if f.endswith(".py"):
                print(f"File Name: {f}")
                dir_path=os.path.join(folder, f)
                print(f"Path: {dir_path}")
                os.system(dir_path)
```

Comment: File Name:  webp.py
Path:  D:\extention\1\webp.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\extention\open.py", line 11, in <module>
    os.system(dir_path)
TypeError: system() argument 'command' must be str, not tuple

Comment: I edited my answer, please try again with the new code.

Comment: `subprocess.run` provides more control over the execution of the command, such as the ability to specify the input, output, and error streams, and to set timeouts. It also allows you to run any command-line program, not just system commands and it is the recommended way to run external commands from Python

Answer (score 1):

This will execute the `.py` file specified by `dir_path`:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run(["python", dir_path])
```

If you need to capture the output, you could use this:

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(["python", dir_path], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, error = process.communicate()
print(output)
```

You only need to integrate one of the alternatives to your code, like this:

```
import os
import subprocess

root_dir = "D:\extention"
for folder, subfolders, files in os.walk(root_dir):
    if folder != root_dir:
        for f in files:
            if f.endswith(".py"):
                print("File Name: ", f)
                dir_path = os.path.join(folder, f)
                print("Path: ", dir_path)
                subprocess.run(["python", dir_path])
```

Comment: File "C:\Users\My Pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1375, in _execute_child
    args = list2cmdline(args)
  File "C:\Users\My Pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 561, in list2cmdline
    for arg in map(os.fsdecode, seq):
  File "C:\Users\My Pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\os.py", line 822, in fsdecode
    filename = fspath(filename)  # Does type-checking of `filename`.
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple

Comment: you are not executing my code, because if you add a `print(type(dir_path))` before the last line you will see that in my example the `dir_path` is `str` 

try again an let me know :)